# Show a small key icon when the prompt asks for a password

Tags: bash, command-line, terminal, zsh, password

How to configure bash/zsh to show a small key icon when the prompt asks for a password like Mac terminal?

[image]

Is this even possible?

Comment: Any particular reason you want this? Any graphic shown in a terminal application would be specific to that app(of custom font glyph). What happens if you ssh from another non-Mac machine?

Comment: I just find it a nice touch, that's all, no other reason. I don't know what happens as I don't own a Mac.

Comment: I'd guess the terminal knows it has echo disabled (eg: `stty -echo`) and puts this icon then. It looks to me it's not a shell feature, it's a terminal-emulator feature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your shell cannot help you because it isn't even active at this point. It's just sitting in the background waiting for the command to terminate. The shell runs the sudo command, after that sudo interacts with the terminal. (Suggested background reading: [What is the exact difference between a 'terminal', a 'shell', a 'tty' and a 'console'?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4126/what-is-the-exact-difference-between-a-terminal-a-shell-a-tty-and-a-con))

It may be possible for your *terminal* to do what Mac terminal does. Certainly Mac terminal has this feature. I'm not aware of other terminals emulators with this feature, you may want to make a feature request to the developer of your favorite terminal emulator.

Answer (score 0):

What you will notice in this case is that typing characters is being accepted by the `read` prompt, just the shell is not echoing them back to you and so it appears that it is not accepting input.